# PDO update, it cant find variable from HTML form

Tags: html, mysql, pdo

I have a problem with parsing data from HTML form. My Form name is "meist", but it says it is undefined, I have tried everything but nothing seems to work. I get an error
"( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: meist in C:\wamp\www\php_sandbox\test.php on line 16"

I think im not able to define meist correctly, but how should I define it so it will recognize it? It says that the rows have been affected, but in database embty string come only. So it cant get the text from the form... please I really need it.

Added new code, If i put _POSTS "meist" in " " it will upload "_POST["meist"] to database but I only need data that is posted in "meist"

Where it gets the infromation to parse later

```
    <?php



?>

<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<form method="post" action="header.php">

    name: <input method="" type="text" id="name" name="name"/> <br>
    <input type="submit" value="add"/>

</body>
</html>
```

Updating data in database

```
 <?php
// configuration
$dbhost     = "localhost";
$dbname     = "webdev1";
$dbuser     = "root";
$dbpass     = "";

// database connection
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass);

// new data
if (isset($_POST["submit"])){
$name = $_POST["name"];
$id = 1;
// query
$sql = "UPDATE user
        SET name=?
        WHERE id=?";
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($name,$id));
echo "tested";
}


?>
```

Comment: Your code is highly vulnerable to [SQL Injection](http://bobby-tables.com). Please read about usage of [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: Before you write **any** more SQL code, you must read up on [properly using PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/), in particular the "prepared statements" section. You **cannot** put `$_POST` data directly into your query without proper escaping.

Answer (score 0):

Correct this

```
<td>
    <input type="text" value="<?php
              // parsing data from database
              foreach($result as $row) {
      echo $row['id']. ' - '. $row['name']. ' - '. $row['tekst'];
    }
        ?>" name="meist" size="20" />
</td>
```

Comment: How ? If i corrected it right, It doesnt do anything, it doesnt even give me the rows that were affeceted just blank page, and nothing happens in database...